# Цвет для псевдоэлемента

Tags: css, sass

Как возможно решить такую проблему? Есть фигура из 3-х css объектов.

```css
body {
    margin: 50px 20px;
}

.main__item_logo {    
     width: 132px;
     height: 100px;    
     position: relative;
     background: orange;
} 

.main__item_logo:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 68px solid transparent;
    border-right: 64px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 35px solid ;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px; 
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 68px solid transparent;
    border-right: 64px solid transparent;
    border-top: 35px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```

[image: скриншот]

Необходимо задать значение цвета для псевдоэлементов в строке `border-top: 35px solid <цвет>;`.

Возможно ли как-то передать это свойство, чтобы не плодить множество классов?
Есть ли возможность получить значение цвета для псевдоэлемента средствами sass, чистого css, без использования js из основного элемента?

Comment: Гляньте мой ответ, может пригодится. Я там с CSS-переменными пример добавил (без препроцессора пример).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цвет границы можно наследовать.

```css
body {
    margin: 50px 20px;
}

.main__item_logo {              
    width: 132px;
    height: 100px;              
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    border-color: blue;
}   

.main__item_logo:before, .main__item_logo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 68px solid transparent;
    border-right: 64px solid transparent;
}

.main__item_logo:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 35px solid;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
    top: 100%;
    border-top: 35px solid;
    border-top-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я же не меняю `color`. Это к соседнемй ответу комментарий, вероятно. Впрочем, есть идея... Если размеры фиксированные, то можно сделать вместо высоты border.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, currentСolor - это цвет текста. Я его НЕ меняю.

Comment: Ага, точно. Простите тупанул:)

Answer (score 2):

1) Задать цвет переменной в SASS, использовать переменную в нужных местах.

2) Если непосредственно внутри элемента не предполагается наличие текста, то можно указать нужное значение в `color` и оно унаследуется для цвета границ у псевдоэлементов:

```css
.main__item_logo {
  width: 132px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fdcf0a;
  color: #fdcf0a; /* цвет границ берется отсюда */
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}

.main__item_logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 68px solid transparent;
  border-right: 64px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 35px solid;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 68px solid transparent;
  border-right: 64px solid transparent;
  border-top: 35px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю @br3t !

Comment: Чтобы окончательно избежать повторений, сделайте для `.main__item_logo` свойство `background: currentColor;`.

Comment: @МихаилСеров Отметьте ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева), если он вам помог.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Спасибо за подсказки. Не знал про currentColor ранее

Answer (score 2):

Улучшеный ответ [@br3t](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/680553/220571) (удалены все возможные повторения):

```css
.main__item_logo {
  width: 132px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: currentColor;
  color: #fdcf0a; /* цвет границ берется отсюда */
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}

.main__item_logo:before,
.main__item_logo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 68px solid transparent;
  border-right: 64px solid transparent;
}

.main__item_logo:before {
  top: 100%;
  border-bottom: 35px solid;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-top: 35px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```

Чтобы вообще ваша фигура была очень гибкой используйте [переменные CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables). Они имеют хорошую поддержку браузеров (почти всё, кроме IE, даже Edge поддерживает).

Таким образом мы можем, к примеру, удалить повторяющееся значение `35px`:

```css
:root {
  --delta_height: 35px;
}

.main__item_logo {
  width: 132px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: currentColor;
  color: #fdcf0a; /* цвет границ берется отсюда */
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}

.main__item_logo:before,
.main__item_logo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 68px solid transparent;
  border-right: 64px solid transparent;
}

.main__item_logo:before {
  top: 100%;
  border-bottom: var(--delta_height) solid;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-top: var(--delta_height) solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```

Таким же образом мы можем ещё дальше продвинуться в параметризации нашей фигуры, чтобы мы могли пропорционально масштабировать наш шестиугольник.

Для этого мы будет использовать CSS `calc` и переменные. Но использование CSS variables вместе с `calc` пока возможно [только в Chrome и Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (см. секцию `Nested calc() with CSS Variables`).

<sub>Изменяйте значение `--r` чтобы это увидеть.</sub>

```css
:root {
  --r: 64px;
  --delta_height: calc(var(--r) / 2);
  --width: calc(var(--r) * 2);
  --height: calc(var(--width) - var(--delta_height));
}

.main__item_logo {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
  background: currentColor;
  color: #fdcf0a; /* цвет границ берется отсюда */
  margin: var(--delta_height) 0;
}

.main__item_logo:before,
.main__item_logo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: var(--r) solid transparent;
  border-right: var(--r) solid transparent;
}

.main__item_logo:before {
  top: 100%;
  border-bottom: var(--delta_height) solid;
}

.main__item_logo:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-top: var(--delta_height) solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__item_logo"></div>
```